# Multiline string is invalid

Tags: zig

I'm writting the below code:

```
pub fn main() !void {
    var array_list = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer array_list.deinit();
    const cwd = fs.cwd();
    const file = try cwd.createFile("files.zig", .{});
    defer file.close();
    const writer = file.writer();
    try writer.print("const std = @import(\"std\");\n", .{});
    try writer.print("pub const file_paths = [_][]const u8{{\n", .{});
    try processDirectory("www", &array_list, writer);
    try writer.print("
        \\};

        \\  const EmbeddedFile = struct {
        \\      path: []const u8,
        \\      content: []const u8,
        \\  };

        \\  try embed();

        \\ pub const embedded_files = blk: {
        \\    var fs: [file_paths.len]EmbeddedFile = undefined;
        \\    for (file_paths) |file_path, i| {
        \\        const embedded_file = EmbeddedFile{
        \\            .path = file_path,
        \\            .content = @embedFile(file_path),
        \\        };
        \\        fs[i] = embedded_file;
        \\    }
        \\    break :blk fs;
        \\}};
    ", .{});
}
```

But got the error:

```
error: expected expression, found 'invalid bytes'
    try writer.print("
                     ^
<stdin>:37:23: note: invalid byte: '\n'
    try writer.print("
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline strings don't need the `"`, they are well-defined by the `\\`

Also I would suggest against putting code into the format string of the print method(this would require escaping all the `{` and `}`), instead I would suggest to pass it as a separate argument:

```
    try writer.print("{s}", .{
        \\};

        \\  const EmbeddedFile = struct {
        \\      path: []const u8,
        \\      content: []const u8,
        \\  };

        \\  try embed();

        \\ pub const embedded_files = blk: {
        \\    var fs: [file_paths.len]EmbeddedFile = undefined;
        \\    for (file_paths) |file_path, i| {
        \\        const embedded_file = EmbeddedFile{
        \\            .path = file_path,
        \\            .content = @embedFile(file_path),
        \\        };
        \\        fs[i] = embedded_file;
        \\    }
        \\    break :blk fs;
        \\}};
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Multiline string literals](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#Multiline-String-Literals) don't use quotation marks (`"`):

```
const hello_world_in_c =
    \\#include <stdio.h>
    \\
    \\int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    \\    printf("hello world\n");
    \\    return 0;
    \\}
;
```